# Boot into Legacy HD option rEFIt

Tags: macos, startup, efi

I just synced my rEFIt partition tool and now I get an option to boot from legacy HD when at the moment the only bootable disk is that cotaining Mac OS X. Has anyone got any idea of how I can get rid of this option from the rEFIt menu?